# C++ Visual Studio Error: name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I'm receiving this error despite the fact that I included the appropriate header file, and the header file is in the same folder as the cpp file.

Here is the header file, msg.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _MYMSG_
#define _MYMSG_

using namespace std;

class Message{
public:
    int type; // type: 0: request, 1: reply
    int rid; // request id
    int opid; // operation id
    int arg1; // argument for operations
    double arg2; // argument for operations

    Message();
    Message (int t, int r, int o, int a1, double a2); 
    char * marshal( int &n); // the result is a string of bytes, the lenghth of which is returned to n
    void unmarshal(const char *, int n); //recover the content in the byte string to the fields
    void print();
};
#endif
```

Here is msg.cpp:

```
#include "msg.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Message::Message()
{

}

Message::Message (int t, int r, int o, int a1, double a2)
{
    type = t;
    rid = r;
    opid = o;
    arg1 = a1;
    arg2 = a2;
}
```

The error is focused on Message::.  Everything looks fine to me, but I'm a novice with bloodshot eyes at this point.

Comment: In your project, do you include both `msg.h` and `msg.cpp`?

Comment: @rcs, no, only msg.h is being included.  There is another cpp/header combination being included (only the header is included) as well, but those two files have no errors.

Comment: Is that header included more than once? Does the compiler see the definition of `Message`? From the error you're getting, it doesn't look like it's been included properly. Try taking out your include guards and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Ryan J, removing pragma once fixed it.  And mysteriously, the error I was getting that forced me to add pragma once has disappeared.  Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Comment: I'm guessing that you have two sets of `msg.h`, perhaps one that Microsoft provided. The inclusion of the first one (in `stdafx.h`?) prevented the inclusion of the second.